# Using Clipping masks in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

Im new to Illustrator and have found the clipping mask is not so easy compared to Phtoshop. Could any one tell me how i can make this line texture a clipping mask over the circle? [image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the lines to be inside the circle....

- Select the circle
- Choose `Edit > Copy`
- Deselect everything
- Choose `Edit > Paste in Front`
- Select the lines and the new circle (the pasted one)
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`

The difference between how Photoshop and Illustrator works regarding this is that you need to define the shape of the mask separately in Illustrator. With Photoshop you can simply clip to an existing layer. In Illustrator you need to specifically create the shape of the mask to be used (the pasted circle above).

Answer (score 1):

As the previous poster said, create what ever shape you want, circle, triangle, whatever, and place it on top of the image (Move to front), and then create the clipping mask. IF you want to undo the clipping mask, right click the image and go to undo clipping mask.