# How to make a clipping mask act like it's supposed to

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, mask

I'll make this more simple than before, since the answer did not work.

[image: http://imgur.com/MCXAqDI]

I need the first shirt with the lines behind it look like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/L8NfuPE]

I just took the lasso tool to create this example, which is not what I want to do. I want to keep it a vector image but have the same outcome.

Comment: What software??

Comment: Scott, sorry. I'm using Illustrator CC

Comment: Please explain what a "normal" clipping path is "supposed" to do? What is your desired image? Your question is unclear. Do you just want a blue and black striped short?

Comment: Scott, yes. Sorry for the confusion. My desired outcome is to have the striped background be on the shirt.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/35368/40478

Comment: You just need to select the *correct* path before creating the clipping mask. It would appear that your black outline is a *shape* (multiple compound shapes) not a just a path. You need to select the *outer* path and copy it, then paste in front to make the clipping mask.

Answer (score -2):

Select transparency inside the t-shirt and make it as a clipping mask for the background layer.