# Illustrator: Create a clipping mask for a long-shadow that was made using the blend tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, illustrator-effects

So I'm trying to make an icon with a long shadow, I used Illustrators blend tool to make the shadow in between my two pigs like so.
[image]

What I would like to do now is create a clipping mask for the long shadow to keep it inside the light blue box that the pig is inside of. I've tried multiple ways to get the clipping mask made, but the truth is, I'm a newbie with Illustrator. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Hi tnormington, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. It seems your questions already has been asked [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35352/using-clipping-masks-in-illustrator). If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the blue box.

Deselect all (`Select > Deselect`)

`Edit > Paste in Front` (will paste the blue box copy on top of everything)

Select the pigs/blend (along with the already selected, pasted, box)

`Object > Clipping Mask > Make`

Comment: Hi @tnormington if this solved your issue, please be sure to mark it as the correct answer on the left.